# how to include multiple custom configuration file to plays application.conf file

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.5

I have about 3 custom configuration files in my play project

1 - mail.conf 2- sms.conf 3 - workflow.conf all in the conf directory of my play project

I can include one of the files by doing what I have below

**include "mail"**

is there a way I can add them at once or I would just have to add them one after the other in the configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can choose another way to implement what you want to do with the following steps

First, config all the default configuration value into your application.conf including mail, sms and workflow

Second, if you want to modify some configurations, just create another conf file and include the application.conf into it, which will override the configuration as you want.

That means you need not to include the 'mail.conf' into the "application.conf", but include the "application.conf" into "mail.conf" where you customize the mail configuration.

Good luck with you